# bind click and keyup of different target to do same function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a submit button, I use `$("#submit")` to perform "myAction function", but in the same time I also want if the user pressed enter, it perform "myAction function"..

I can't do like this

```
$("#submit").on('click keyup', function(){
 //myAction function
});
```

because I have to attach the keyup event to my input field instead of #submit..

Comment: Just use an html `form` element with a `submit` event listener.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give a name to your function and bind both event on the selector. Then add a special condition:

```
function send(e){
    if(e.type == 'click' || (e.type == 'keyup' && e.wich == 13))
}

$('[type=text]').on('keyup', send);
$('[type=submit]').on('click', send);
```

Answer (score 1):

Write your `my action` as a separate function and use it as below

```
function myAction() {
    console.log('act');
    //do your stuff here
}
$("#submit").on('click', myAction);
$("input.enter").on('keypress', function (e) {
    //enter key code is 13
    if (e.which == 13) {
        myAction()
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MjWcN/)